# Обводка SVG в Internet Explorer не отображается

Tags: css, svg

Для того, чтобы задать нестандартную обводку блоку, использую в качестве фона SVG. Цвет обводки задаю так `stroke: #FFD200`. Но если задавать цвет в HEX-формате, то обводка не отображается в IE(11), FireFox. Если задавать в RGB, то в FireFox работает. Есть ли какой-то кроссбраузерный вариант установки цвета?

```css
.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: none; stroke: #FFD200; stroke-width: 6; stroke-dasharray: 6 3'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```